# TextView Background without drawable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, drawable

I want to make my TextView background color without the drawable on the left like this:

[image]

But when I'm trying to do it I got like this:

[image]

This is my textview code:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Typetxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space0"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_type_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
```

and in the Adapter this is the code for coloring the background:

```
 holder.Typetxt.setText(posts.getTRADE_TYPE_NAME());
    if(posts.getTRADE_TYPE_NAME().equals("VL")){
        holder.Typetxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7464"));
        holder.Typetxt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vl_background);
        holder.cardViewMain.setBackgroundResource(R.color.VLBackground);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this layout without using a drawable. Make the `cardView's` background color, same as the color you want on the left side strip. Add a `ConstraintLayout` inside it and give this `ConstraintLayout` white background color and a `marginStart` of whatever size you want your strip width to be.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                tools:text="Lorem \nipsum \ndolor" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

The background is set for the entire view-  not just the text.  If you're using a drawableStart, that includes the drawable.  If you don't want that, use 2 views, an ImageView and a TextView.